# Почему дом желтый?

Tags: фразеология

Есть устойчивое выражение для обозначения сумасшедшего дома - "желтый дом". Например: *"Зорин никогда мне не признавался, что он сошел с ума; а, напротив, уверял меня, что если доктора и смотрители **желтого дома** не безумные, так по одному упрямству и злобе не хотят видеть, что у него вместо правой ноги отличная гитара". М.Н. Загоскин, «Вечер на Хопре»"*
Но откуда взялось это выражение? Почему именно желтый?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Первоначально Дом призрения был выкрашен в традиционный для Петербурга жёлтый цвет. Но именно он стал решающим признаком для народного названия этого богоугодного заведения — «Жёлтый дом». Очень скоро эта идиома стала аллегорией всех домов сумасшедших."
Тем не менее, до сих пор традиция красить больницы , да и здания в стиле классицизма, в желтый цвет не изменилась.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что  Обуховская психиатрическая больница для умалишённых была выкрашена в жёлтый цвет, другие - по аналогии с ней, потом даже специально стали красить такие больницы в жёлтый - символ болезненности.